# How To Install MediaWiki 'Notes' Extension

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions, mediawiki-templates

I'm using `MediaWiki 1.32` and I've been trying to get the **Template:Note** to work. From what I gathered, I don't have the **Note** template installed in my `wiki/extensions` folder.

My goal is to create Info/Warning/Danger type of short notes (with a small icon) similar to the ones found at the top of the [following page.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module:Hatnote)

If this extension is not available, are there any similar Note Extensions I could download/install. Or should I create this Note's effect using `MediaWiki` Table manually, as described below?

```
{|class="wikitable"
 | [[File:Info-icon.png]]
 | This Message is the least ugliest fancy table
|}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question starts to date but anyway...

You don't need any extension to do that, just use a template, lets call it `Template:Note`, with this content:

```
<includeonly>{|class="wikitable"
 | [[File:Info-icon.png]]
 | {{{1}}}
|}</includeonly>
```

And call it as follows:

```
{{Note|This Message is the least ugliest fancy table}}
```

Comment: Thanks @IRA1777 - This worked. And I got to know the power of Templates in Wiki.